# python 3.9 isdigit() not working with raw_input()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello there im learning Python, using Python 3.9 with a simple piece of code, testing out isdigit() with raw_input()

see code below.

```
year = raw_input()

if str(year).isdigit() == True:
    print "This is a number"
else:
    print "this is not a number"
```

when i enter a number ie ( 23 ) i only get "This is not a number"

I know this question has been asked many times, but this does not work,
Very frustrating

could someone point me in the right direction please.

Regards Rob

Comment: You say you're using Python 3.9, but `raw_input()` does not exist in Python 3.

Comment: Do you have to use input to test `'23'.isdigit()`? E.g. The issue appears to be how you've typed the input rather than isdigit function

Comment: Also `print "This is a number"` is not a valid statement in Python 3. If this runs at all, then you're using Python 2.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you input. Is it ``23``, or ``( 23 )``, or ``23 ``, or...

Comment: Yes you are spot on,  Book written for Python 2,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably following a resource written for python 2.x not 3.9, you would want to switch `raw_input()` with `input()`.
Also replace `print "This is a number"` with `print("This is a number")`

Are you sure you are using python 3.9? That code does not work in it.

Comment: Code is still being ran with Python2 anyway

Comment: @OneCricketeer he said he was using python 3.9, so he is probably following a wrong guide.

Comment: If he was, then it wouldn't run at all

Answer (score 0):

python 3 doesn't have `raw_input`. it was available in python 2.

```
year = input()

if str(year).isdigit() == True:
    print ("This is a number")
else:
    print ("this is not a number")
```

Does this do what you were looking for?

Comment: YES that works fine, thank you.

Also when using input() is there a way i can enter text without having to use quotes.  You can type in numbers without quotes, but can this be done without quote when inputting text.??

Comment: @Rob If you have to enter quotes to get `input()` to work then you're still using Python 2. Solve that first.